# Test connection was NOT successful...Database not found of no system permission

Tags: odbc, informix

I am having difficulty connecting to a existing Informix database. I am attempting to mimic the configuration that is present on another machine which currently works. By the way, that other machine is on the same network and it is accessing the DB through a tunnel, so I am pretty sure the issue isn't related to the network configuration.

Regardless, here are the steps that I took to try and make the connection

- Downloaded clientsdk.3.50.TC9DE and installed this. The working machine uses 3.50.TC2DE, but I couldn't find the installer for that version. (Note that at first I tried using 3.50TC9, not sure if that makes a difference)
- Matched the ODBC config in the new machine to the working machine

  - The working machine has a host name in the Host Name field. I assume this was allowed because the host was set to an IP in the hosts file. Regardless, I am using the IP.
  - Also I am using C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe to create the DSN
- Made sure that the INFORMIXDIR and PATH directory were correct. as per http://www.dbforums.com/informix/694408-odbc-test-connection-not-successful.html#post2633932 I don't think the locales are the issue because they aren't set in the working machine's Setnet32. Also, I made sure that the locales matched in the ODBC environment settings.

  - Also, since my INFORMIXDIR is in C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Informix\Client-SDK\bin I tried replacing Program Files (x86) with PROGRAM~2 and Client-SDK with CLIENT~1 to no avail.
  - Tried setting INFORMIXDIR directly in my system environment variables (outside of Setnet32)
- Set DBPATH to match the working system in both the user and system environment variables.
- Set INFORMIXSERVER to the server in both Setnet and the system environment variables.
- Completely lowered the firewall on my machine.
- I can ping and telnet into the server.

I have also tried..

- Tried this on Windows XP
- Tested the ILogin demo. The result was a popup that stated Customer Records Found in the title bar with an empty text area field.
- Reinstalled into C:\informix instead of C:\Program Files(x86)...
- Rebooted after various steps.

At this point I am at a loss. Has anyone run into this? The only other things I can think of is that I am using Win7 64-bit (with 32 bit drivers) and that the driver is 9DE not 2DE.

Comment: Is the other machine a Windows 7 64-bit machine too? The TC2DE vs TC9DE should not be a factor.  I am worried about whether 3.50 works with Windows 7, but I've not yet checked the release notes to see what it says.  OTOH, I think 3.50 predates Windows 7, hence the question about the other machine.

Comment: The other server is Windows Server 2003. I am getting to the point where I am going to get another instance with 2003 up to rule that out.

Comment: Never mind, a co-worker already tried this on WinXP and got the same error. I will still try 2003 since I am at a loss for other solutions. BTW, I have tried the ilogin demo and I get pop up that says Customer Records Found with a blank text area with a header of Number First Name Last Name.

Comment: I would expect CSDK 3.50 to work with WinXP and Win2K3.  Ideally, upwards compatibility would mean it works with Win7 too; it was certainly not unreasonable to try.  Windows is not my strongest subject — to be polite about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so half of the battle is over. I was able to get a "Test connection was successful" on my Win7 machine. We had a copy of the 2.90.TC6 driver available in our file server from way back. I installed it and it worked. So my guess is that the database I am working with isn't compatible with 3.50.TC9DE.

I guess my next course of action is to try and find an installer for 3.50.TC2DE so that I can match the production system.

Comment: **Note:** I am not going to mark my own answer as accepted until either I can find  the most current driver that works or I fully test out the  2.90 driver to make sure it works for my needs. I am uneasy about using the 2.90 driver since it may have issues that were resolved in later versions.

Comment: It's done. It works. I am not sure if the 2.90 driver would have done the trick, but I found another version, 3.00.TC3DE. I installed it and I was able to get my local app to do everything I needed it to (it was just doing simple selects, updates, and deletes). It is mimicking the production server perfectly. With that said, I am marking this solution as accepted. A word of advice to anyone in DevOps, save your installers or any other important pieces of your system.